# AWS Lambda function not accepting Twilio Module

Tags: node.js, module, twilio, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Whenever I try to include `Twilio` module in my Lambda Function, it gives out an error:

> "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'twilio'"

The error is on line:

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
```

Can anyone help me out with the way we can include modules?

Comment: Your question seems to be 'Am I including this module correctly?' which could be answered. As a tip, formatting your code as code (wrap in backticks [`]) makes it easier to read. Don't be surprised if someone asks for a more complete code sample.

Comment: I'm definitely including the module correctly as this is the same procedure as carried out for NodeJs code that runs on local server, and there we install module by using "npm" on terminal window. But in the case of AWS Lambda there is no such terminal window to install the module

Comment: Have you included the `node_modules` folder with your uploaded zip package?  I have a separate directory with my lambda node packages and lambda function files.  A common gotcha is zipping the directory and not the _contents of_ the directory.  So `zip -r twilioLambda.zip .` when in the directory that holds your lambda function and node modules.

Comment: I haven't uploaded any zip package. I just wrote the code in the editor provided by AWS Lambda categorised as: "Edit Code Inline".

Comment: You need to also upload the package with your function.  I suggest creating a separate/new directory just for your Lambda package.  Include your lambdafunc.js file and locally install the NPM packages with `npm install twilio` while in this new directory.  Then click upload .zip in the lambda page where you're writing your code now.

Comment: The reason Lambda can't find the Twilio module is because it sounds like it's not there.

Comment: You can test whether or not your Lambda function will work once uploaded by testing whether or not it works locally in a separate directory with the Twilio module.

Comment: Also here's a helpful one liner that will replace your Lambda function code: `aws lambda update-function-code --function-name lambda --zip-file fileb://~/path/.to/lambda/lambda.zip`

Answer (score 5):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's a really good tutorial on how to include npm modules in Lambda written by the AWS team. It shows [how to use Node.js packages in Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/).

The short version is that you should build your Lambda function locally as you would any other Node.js script, installing the modules as you go into the script. Then, once it is working, zip up your entire directory, including the `node_modules` directory inside, and use Lambda’s createFunction API, CLI, or the console UI to deploy it.